# How can I align a varchar field to the right in TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have values like " 11(space)", "109", "X(space)(space)", "9(space)(space)", "15(space)" etc. in a column called MyCode that is varchar(3).

When I order them I have a prolbme like 11 appears before 109 when I ORDER them in ASC order.

I want to align the values to right by adding empty char in front so that ORDER would result:

```
 " 11"

 .. 

"109"
```

**Question**: How can I write my SELECT MyChar FROM MyTable so that for a value "1(space)(space)" it should return "(space)(space)1" etc. ?

---

@gbn: Your answer did what I needed but the output didnt change:

[image]

Comment: If you save numbers as text, they get sorted as text unless you cast them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to always pad with leading spaces to a fixed length

```
SELECT RIGHT(
      SPACE(5) + 
      REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(RTRIM(MyChar), CHAR(160), ''), CHAR(9), ''), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), '')
    , 5) AS Justified
FROM MyTable 
ORDER BY Justified
```

If you change one `5`, you need to change both

Edit: added RTRIM

Edit 2: added hard space + other non-printable detection

What does this give you?

```
SELECT ASCII(RIGHT(MyChar, 1) FROM MyTable
```

Comment: It creates "  11 " instead of "  11". So it does not help me to solve my ordering problem

Comment: Are they real spaces or "hard spaces"? (character 160)