# How can I ORDER anything that looks like a number, as a number in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have a column named Code that is varchar(3).

It contains numbers and strings as well. For example: `'  1', '234', 'Xxx', '9  ','Aa '` etc.

Is there way -just like in MS EXCEL- ORDER anything that looks like a number, as a number?

So that output for the given example above will be:

```
1. 1 
2. 234 
3. 9 
4. Aa 
5. Xxx
```

Comment: Hmmm. Your desired output looks like normal sort order to me.

Comment: How does this differ from your recent question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/9162346/27535 right aligning will force a numeric sort with the string one to " 11" comes before "109"

Comment: Unfortunately no. Bcoz, when there is "109" and "11 ", 109 comes before 11 in the results.

Comment: That is how it will order the results. If you want to order anything that looks like a number as a number, then 234 should be after 9

Comment: @gbn: In the previous one I was asking the alingment -with a hope that it would help- but here I ask ORDERING logic isntead.

Comment: @pencilCake: So, explain here how the previous answer doesn't work for you...

Comment: @gbn: I have attached a screenshot to the relevant question.

Comment: @pencilCake: if RTRIM fails, then you don't have spaces. YOu have hard spaces, or tabs etc

Comment: @gbn: How can I prove your assumption? I mean to test if it is not spaces?

Comment: @pencilCake: I updated in the other answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(YourField) = 1 THEN CONVERT(INT, YourField) - 500 ELSE ASCII(LOWER(YourField)) END
```

If the field can be converted to a number it is sorted by number otherwise it uses ASCII coding to sort. I have used "- 500" just so there is no cross over in the sort, and to ensure numbers are sorted ahead of text.

---

**ADDENDUM:**

[Brian Arsuaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038218/brian-arsuaga) has posted a more robust solution to this which I actually prefer, but since this has already been marked as the answer I am adding his solution to this for the benefit of anyone reading this in the future.

```
ORDER BY 
        ISNUMERIC(YourField) DESC, 
        CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(YourField) = 1 THEN CONVERT(INT, YourField) ELSE 0 END,
        YourField
```

Comment: I didn't get the point for the -500. Can you elaborate that please?

Comment: The "- 500" is to take the converted int values away from the ascii values in the sort - for example without it "X" would appear before any number higher than 120 (the result of ASCII("x")). 500 was an arbitrary figure I chose because it was larger than any number in your sample. The number you pick should be higher than the maximum size of your data, so with a varchar(3) column it would be better to use 1000 instead of 500

Comment: I've just noticed that would not do what you asked in the question, I am guessing since you've said it worked your question contains a mistake. The output of your data using the method I posted would put 9 before 234.

Comment: @GarethD : IT does that. But I have changed -500 to -1000. That is correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like using an arbitrary sentinel (500), which might cause sorting issues depending on the range of numbers you expect, you can use multiple expressions for the ordering.

```
-- put the numbers at the top
ORDER BY ISNUMERIC(YourField) DESC,
       -- sort the numbers as numbers, sort the strings as nothing
       CONVERT(INT, CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(YourField) = 1 THEN YourField ELSE '0' END),
       -- sort the strings
       YourField
```

The last term is only a tiebreaker when either two terms are both numbers with the same value ('01', '1') or two terms are both non-numbers.  For non-numbers, their first and second terms will always be 0.

More complicated, but maybe a little more safe.

Edited to add a nice comparison with the help of the guy below

```
create table #t
(
    YourField varchar(4)
)
insert into #t(YourField) Values('1'), ('3'), ('234'), ('0'), ('00'),
   ('09'), ('9'), ('1a'), ('aaa'), ('aba'), ('-500')

Select YourField from #t

  ORDER BY ISNUMERIC(YourField) DESC,
           CONVERT(INT, CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(YourField) = 1 THEN YourField ELSE '0' END),
           YourField

drop table #t
```

[image: example results]

Comment: +1 I prefer this to my answer. If I knew how I would unmark mine as the answer and make this the answer, since I don't know how I've added an addendum to my answer to indicate your better method.